# Copy changes from one mysql database to other

Tags: mysql

I Need to create a script which every night take the changes from one MySQL database and copy to another.
How can I do this? Can you give me some SQL query which selects all changes on the database?
The replication is not possible. Need exactly the script.

Thanks.

P.S. I can' get a full snapshot of the database every time. I Need to select only the changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Replication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402794/mysql-replication)

Comment: Sorry but I can't do replication. Need to create the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database's binary log is actually logging all the changes(i.e. DML like INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE etc, as well as DDL like ALTER TABLE, CREATE INDEX etc) within your database.

So what you need to do is use some commands like mysqlbinlog to extract the changes periodically.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achive is incremental backup. Mysql provides `mysqldump` and `mysqlhotcopy` scripts that can achieve this if binary log is enabled, see [mysql documentation on backup methods](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html) for details.